# DRCSIM: The BDI tutorial is wrong

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was testing the "Using Atlas Sim Interface" Turorial of the drcsim v2.5 but it seems to be wrong. The tutorial is using the structure currently described at the UserGuide but that is not what i got on my computer.

As an example, the step_queue is actually called step_data.

Other example, the walk_state is a sub-part of behavior_feedback and not directly placed at the AtlasSimInterfaceState.

I believe the documentation and the tutorial are referring to a newer version. However I can't find any new updates.

Regards,

LR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2702/drcsim:-the-bdi-tutorial-is-wrong.../) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi LR,

The changes from drcsim 2.5.x to 2.6.x-candidate (now built in drcsim-nightly) can be found in [DRCSim RoadMap](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Roadmap).

[BDI controller AtlasSimInterface 1.1.0 overview and ROS API can be found in the DRCSim User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#Boston_Dynamics_Atlas_Simulation_Behavior_Library_.28AtlasSimInterface.29).  Underlying C-style data structures and API of the library can be found [here](http://gazebosim.org/drc/api/atlas_interface/index.html).

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0